# Find real (optical) center of SVG icons using SCSS mixin

Tags: svg, sass, center, mixins

So I was reading through this pretty interesting (and accurate) article on the play button never being centered optically -

https://medium.com/@erqiudao/the-play-button-is-not-optical-alignment-4cea11bda175

After reading this I wanted to try and take a stab at creating a mixin that will **always** find the actual center of an icon no matter the shape of it. But! It is a lot trickier than I thought it would be so came here for some help!

Oh and side note: currently I am passing all of my svg icons into a font file that has some base styles on it such as:

```
font-family:"IconFont";
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:1;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
speak:none;
text-decoration:inherit;
text-transform:none;
text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
```

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

Best,
Artem

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but as it stands currently I think the question may be too broad for a good answer. Is there a specific issue you're running into with your mixin?

Comment: Well not particularly. Right now we are passing all our icons through a generated web-font, which is great in some cases but a bother in other.

So for the play-button example, since the center of the container isn't the actual optical center, we need to add on other paddings, and adjustments so it centers optically and looks nice. 

But would want to somehow calculate that center without manually adjusting

Comment: Well, it sounds to me like you'd probably need to add some [custom functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions) to Sass to handle the brunt of the calculations, since I doubt the built-in functions are sufficient for what you want. You could integrate some Ruby library to handle SVG parsing (like [this one](https://github.com/awebneck/savage) maybe). But without a [specific, answerable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I think this question will (and should) be closed...